# HOW To remove ' in a column SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005-express

I have a specific column (`description`) in a particular table. I used bulk loading to insert data in table, but in retrieving data it's giving an error because of this column (`description`).

The problem is occuring due to `'` in description (like `12' height`).
So how can I remove this `'` in that column?

Comment: There is no reason that should give an error. Please post the actual error along with the code that generates the error.

Answer (score 1):

[Is sounds like you are running some kind of script that fails when it tries to insert a value with a single quote in its value, between two quotes in code or dynamic sql. Your problem won't be in the database, it will be where you are processing it. A quick hack would be to run an update replace. In this case I am deleting your empty quotes.

`Update [tablename]
set [description] = replace([description],char(39),'') 

where [description] like '%' + char(39) + '%'`

However this is just a hack....your problem is somewhere else where you are retrieving and processing the data